# How can I create 3 way radio buttons in MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently I am storing my radio button as a bool

```
Nullable<bool> HasConnector {get; set;}
```

In the view I have three radio buttons true false and I check the third for null and then display the radiobutton as checked if it is null.

```
            @if(Model.PdsToEdit.HasConnector.HasValue)
            {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.PdsToEdit.HasConnector, string.Empty)
            }else
            {
             @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.PdsToEdit.HasrConnector, string.Empty, new { Checked= "checked"})   
            }
```

How could I simplify this is there any data annotation in MVC5 for null bools so I can keep my view clean?

Comment: Try the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752013/mvc3-editortemplate-for-a-nullable-boolean-using-radiobuttons

Comment: Thanks, I saw that already though, not a very elegant addition.