# Allow Nullable<bool> in ASP.NET MVC form on submission

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, modelstate

I have a model with some properties being of type Nullable.

```
public Nullable<bool> Continuing { get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> Incomplete { get; set; }

//..etc other properties omitted for brevity
```

I have successfully bound this in a form with 3 radio buttons but when I submit the form, `ModelState.IsValid` returns false.

The controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateSub(MyModel model)
        {
            var errors = ModelState
                        .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                        .Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors })
                        .ToArray();
```

I had a look at the errors and it is saying that the value  `'null'` is not allowed for the properties of type `Nullable<bool>` - I don't seem to understand why.

the error:

[image]

EDIT:

This is how I am binding the properties to the radios:

```
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Continuing, true, new {@class = "Continuing-true", style="visibility: hidden; margin-left:-13px"})
                <label class="btn-cohort btn btn-sm btn-default @if(Model.Continuing.HasValue && Model.Continuing.Value) { <text>btn-custom-green active</text> } " data-value="true">
                        <input type="radio" name="options" value="true" />
                        T
                </label>

                @if(!Model.Continuing.HasValue) { 
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Continuing, "null", new {@checked = "checked", @class = "Continuing-null", style="visibility: hidden; margin-left:-13px"}) 
                } else {
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Continuing, "null", new {@class = "Continuing-null", style="visibility: hidden; margin-left:-13px"}) 
                }
                <label class="btn-cohort btn btn-sm btn-default btn-n  @if(!Model.Continuing.HasValue) { <text>active</text> } " data-value="null">
                        <input type="radio" name="options" value="null"/>
                        N
                </label>

                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Continuing, false, new {@class = "Continuing-false", style="visibility: hidden; margin-left:-13px"})
                <label class="btn-cohort btn btn-sm btn-default @if(Model.Continuing.HasValue && !Model.Continuing.Value) { <text>btn-custom-red active</text> } " data-value="false">
                        <input type="radio" name="options" value="false" />
                        F
                </label>
            </div>
```

Comment: Show how you are generating the radio buttons in the view (best guess is you have given the radio button a value of `"null"` instead of `""`).

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have edited my post, I can see why it is useful to include this in my OP but at first I omitted it because it was a bit messy as I am using bootstrap styled radios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Html helper usage to

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Continuing, "", ...)
```

and the manual html to

```
<input ... value="" />
```

so they posts back and empty string as opposed to a `string` with the value `"null"` which the `ValueProviders` cannot convert to `null`

Comment: This will create a problem later on because when I am saving this to the database I want the values to actually be null and not empty strings.

Comment: It will be `null` when it bound - the `ValueProviders` convert an empty string to null, but cant convert the string `"null"` to `null` - remember your just posting key/value pairs - its all effectively strings

Comment: Oh I understand now, I thought the problem is that it wouldn't allow nulls, not because it can't convert "null" to null. Thanks

Comment: And you have a few other odd things in your code such as `@checked = "checked"` - which will be completely ignored so is a bit pointless. The whole purpose of using strongly typed helpers is to bind to your model properties, so its the value of `Continuing` which determines whats selected (not `@checked = "checked"`) - and thankfully because model binding would all fail if didn't :)

Comment: Yes, this is strange but it is a workaround to a problem I was having when submitting the form and reloading the page with the same model, the values that were selected to be true would come back as null for some reason.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16047172/3281466 - this is the problem I was having, handling the special null case.

Comment: That should not happen, and may disappear now that you change `"null"` to `""`. If not, I suggest to post a new question, showing the view and also the controller. In any case the answer you linked to is utter nonsense and I cant believe it was voted up or accepted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76452/discussion-between-user3281466-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: Yes it did disappear after the change. Thanks.